# Get rid of extra commas from excel file with python

Tags: python

I've got a csv file and whenever i access the elements it gets me

aapl,2001-12-4,,,,,

The commas at the end is causing my functions to not work properly for my other application. How can I remove this in order to get rid of any additional commas after elements?

for example the above after correction would be

aaple,2001-12-4

anything will help, thanks so much.

m

Comment: @Marcin: in this context, they actually don't. When Excel saves a csv file, it assumes the data is rectangular - so all rows are padded out with blank fields until the rows are all the same length. This is problematic if you use Excel as your CSV editor - the excess commas don't show up and your file looks identical to the original. It only shows once you open the CSV in a  text editor.

Comment: the application i am using has a function called getFieldCount, and it is treating each of those empty slots within them as a field. All of them has got 7 counts which is not what I want as I only want the counter to count fields with elements in them. I havent tried much, but manually doing it is not a long term solution so I thought I'd give it a shot with a question. Also I am learning python so it be a good way to learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to remove the excess commas from the right hand side of a string:

```
In [2]: mystring = '1,2,3,4,"Hello!",,,,,,,,,'

In [3]: mystring.rstrip(',')
Out[3]: '1,2,3,4,"Hello!"'

In [4]:
```

Expand on this to perform the comma-stripping operation for each line of a file:

- Open the original .csv file.
- Process one line, removing excess commas.
- Write the processed line to a new file.
- Repeat until your original .csv file is completely processed.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you remove the trailing commas? Typically the commas with no value between them would mean that the particular field is empty.

It would be better I think to not modify the line/file, but instead utilize in your application a method to split the line on commas. Then, do what you need to do with the list of data

```
import csv

csv_file = file('test.csv', 'rU')
csv_list = csv.reader(csv_file)

for k in csv_list:
    print filter(None,k)

>>>
 ['aapl','2001-02-4']
```

Comment: In this instance the trailing commas really are meaningless - they're added automatically when you save a CSV file from Excel. See my comment on the OP. Also, "utilize in your application a method..." only applies if the .csv file is for consumption in Python. The way I read the OP, he has to feed the .csv file to a *third-party* app which is barfing on the extra commas. (I know 'cause this has actually happened to me.)

Comment: @Li-aungYip Added a bit of additional code to show how this method can still be utilized. This way, the file contents are not modified, but the resulting list meets the questions requirement.

Comment: Good solution but subtle bug: What is `filter(None,[0,1,2,3,None,5,6,None,None])`? a) zeros are discarded because they're logical False, which is probably not a good behaviour and b) the 5th field is discarded though it's in the middle of the row - this *could* be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.rstrip`:

```
>>> 'aapl,2001-12-4,,,,,'.rstrip(',')
'aapl,2001-12-4'
```

Answer (score 0):

If in case you can use `sed` then you can do this way from command line

`sed -re 's/,*$//g' temp.csv`

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest tricks is to use the parameter `usecols` in the `read_csv` function to limit what columns you read in:

For example

```
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import files
import io
uploaded = files.upload()
x_train = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['x_train.csv'].decode('utf-8')), skiprows=1, usecols=range(10) ,header=None)
```

To limit the reader to read only 10 columns, since the comma will be on the column 11.